# Using the distanceTo method

Tags: java, android

My code should accept locations that has accuracy under 100, if the new location accuracy is **smaller** then the old more in 20 then use the new one.
Also if the distance from the new location to the old one is larger then 200 use it.

I have no idea why but after testing my code I got the following locations in my db:

[image]

The last 3 records are less then 200m from each other, how come I use them??
Here is the code:

```
int Aloc = (int) loc.getAccuracy();
int AnewLoc = (int) newLoc.getAccuracy();
if(Aloc > AnewLoc +20)
    sendTask();
else
{
    float distance = loc.distanceTo(newLoc);
    if(distance > 200)
        sendTask();
}
```

This code is executed to locations that their accuracy is less then 100.

**EDIT**
after changing the condition to

```
if((AnewLoc+20) < Aloc)
```

I received the following records:
[image]

The new records has larger accuracy then the old one and his distance is less then 200(0.01407 km which is 14 meters). I can't understand how come it pass by the code and sent to the db.

Comment: it is possible you are saving the location after your treatment and meanwhile receive other locations

Comment: Can you add to your output also the result of distance, or a trace log to see which of the sendTask calls is being executed?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want use a larger accuracy? It means that the location is less precise. Normally you want to do things if the value returned by accuracy is smaller, since it means the new location is more precise.

Comment: Smaller accuracy, why larger? smaller. here is an example Aloc = 70 AnewLoc = 30. if(70>30+20) == true execute the task.  EDIT: sorry about that I edited my post.

Comment: Image is blocked. Your first priority is newLocation should be greater that oldLocation after adding 20. is that Working fine? if yes then we can talk to else condition.

Comment: My first priority is newLocation+20 is smaller then oldLocation. I have no idea if it's working since I receive wrong locations in my db as you can see.

Comment: I just putted 2 break lines in the sendTask() lines so I could see the distance or the accuracy values before it send the task and see whats wrong

Comment: Ok remove else location just have only if location and see if you are still getting wrong entry in db. or those where old entry which got inserted accidently. If your first condition works fine then we will move to else condtion.

Comment: May be you are displaying record which are not in inserted order. try to display record in inserted order by date or record_id. This will give you exact result for analyze.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23950/discussion-between-real-and-imri-persiado)

Comment: Got the solution or still struggling

Comment: Still debugging, looks like when I debug everything is fine but when I run it normally then the error occurs weird. Give me more a hour.

Answer (score 1):

Change your checking logic like this

```
int Aloc = (int) loc.getAccuracy();
int AnewLoc = (int) newLoc.getAccuracy();
if(AnewLoc < ( Aloc+20))
    sendTask();
else
{
    float distance = loc.distanceTo(newLoc);
    if(distance > 200)
        sendTask();
}
```

This should work

Comment: I will test it and let you know if it's working but as you can see the problem was on the distanceTo case and you didn't changed a thing. maybe I'm wrong I will test and update you.

Comment: @Real I think that the only difference is that you added () around the sum. That shouldn't have any effect, since the additive operators have more precedence than relational (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html ) In addition, since the relational operators return a boolean, the wrong placement of the place should give a compiler error.

Comment: I have changed the order also.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. You are right, the 64-64 case confused me but that got in probably due to the second sendTask.

Comment: But this condition: AnewLoc > ( Aloc+20) is false since I would like to execute the task only if AnewLoc less then Aloc+20.

Comment: I edited my post I ment smaller not larger.. I'm testing your code right now.

Comment: Write your loc.distanceTo(newLoc) method in question

Comment: It's a method inside the Location class

Comment: Is that your custom class a thrid party provided class

Comment: No it's the android location class.

Comment: Ok sorry I have no idea about android classes. I am a J2EE guy.